# All the Xenodromes

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence, base-conversion, integer

## Introduction

A xenodrome in base *n* is an integer where all of its digits in base *n* are different. [Here](https://oeis.org/search?q=Xenodromes) are some OEIS sequences of xenodromes.

For example, in base 16, `FACE`, `42` and `FEDCBA9876543210` are some xenodromes (Which are `64206`, `66` and `18364758544493064720` in base 10), but `11` and `DEFACED` are not.

## Challenge

Given an input base, *n*, output out all xenodromes for that base *in base 10*.

The output should be in order of least to greatest. It should be clear where a term in the sequence ends and a new one begins (e.g. `[0, 1, 2]` is clear where `012` is not.)

*n* will be an integer greater than 0.

### Clarifications

This challenge does IO specifically in base 10 to avoid handling integers and their base as strings. The challenge is in abstractly handling any base. As such, I am adding this additional rule:

**Integers cannot be stored as strings in a base other than base 10.**

Your program should be able to theoretically handle reasonably high *n* if there were no time, memory, precision or other technical restrictions in the implementation of a language.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program, in bytes, wins.

## Example Input and Output

```
1  # Input
0  # Output
```

```
2
0, 1, 2
```

```
3
0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 11, 15, 19, 21
```

```
4
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 18, 19, 24, 27, 28, 30, 33, 35, 36, 39, 44, 45, 49, 50, 52, 54, 56, 57, 75, 78, 99, 108, 114, 120, 135, 141, 147, 156, 177, 180, 198, 201, 210, 216, 225, 228
```

Comment: is there a limit to n?

Comment: @Flp.Tkc No. It should be able to handle reasonably high n. I don't want the challenge to be limited by how high a base the builtin base conversion of a language can handle.

Comment: @Artyer That should have been part of the challenge text, then. It seems some answers are already doing that

Comment: I know the base conversion in Pyth can handle values [larger that 36](http://pyth.tryitonline.net/#code=aVE2Nw&input=WzU1LCA1Nl0&debug=on), but since this wants all of the xenodromes, the underlying python breaks when the list gets too large, saying it can't fit a value in a `ssize_t`. Is it breaking in this way acceptable?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Yes. The algorithm is not the problem there, but the implementation, which is ok.

Comment: Somebody seems to have downvoted all answers that cannot handle larger bases because of a built-in precision limit, which also seems like an implementation rather than an algorithm problem. Could you clarify?

Comment: @Dennis I have clarified the rules. I _think_ the new rule about ints as strings is what I wanted. I will post in the sandbox next time though.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but certainly the answers didn't fulfill that requirement. I think it's better to relax that requirement, as you have done now

Comment: Most languages that allow arbitrarily large integers (like Python, which the current winning solution in Pyth is based on) store them internally as strings in base 256 or base 2^32 or something similar. Also, if fixed-length strings still count as strings, then technically *everything* on a computer is stored as strings of base 2 digits. Perhaps you should at least clarify whether using built-in bignum implementations or libraries is allowed, or whether we need to either stick to fixed-length integers or implement our own large integer arithmetic in base 10?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## [Pyth](http://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 8 bytes

```
f{IjTQU^
```

Filters the numbers in **[0, n^n - 1]** on having no duplicate elements in base **n**. The base conversion in Pyth will work with any base, but since this looks at a very quickly increasing list of numbers, it will eventually be unable to store the values in memory.

[Try it online!](http://pyth.tryitonline.net/#code=ZntJalRRVV4&input=NA)

#### Explanation:

```
f{IjTQU^QQ    - Auto-fill variables
      U^QQ    - [0, n^n-1]
f             - keep only those that ...
 {I           - do not change when deduplicated
   jTQ        - are converted into base n
```

Comment: Wow, a solution that's shorter than the Jelly solution that Dennis made! :'P

Comment: No one beats Jelly. ¶:

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>9</s> 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ð*ḶbQ€Qḅ
```

*Thanks to @JonathanAllan for golfing off 1 byte!*

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=w7Aq4bi2YlHigqxR4biF&input=&args=Mw) or [verify all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=w7Aq4bi2YlHigqxR4biFCsOH4oKsRw&input=&args=MSwgMiwgMywgNA).

#### How it works

```
ð*ḶbQ€Qḅ  Main link. Argument: n

ð         Make the chain dyadic, setting both left and right argument to n.
          This prevents us from having to reference n explicitly in the chain.
 *        Compute nⁿ.
  Ḷ       Unlength; yield A := [0, ..., nⁿ - 1].
   b      Convert each k in A to base n.
    Q€    Unique each; remove duplicate digits.
      Q   Unique; remove duplicate digit lists.
       ḅ  Convert each digit list from base n to integer.
```

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2, 87 bytes

```python
n=input()
for x in range(n**n):
 s={n};a=x
 while{a%n}|s>s:s|={a%n};a/=n
 print-~-a*`x`
```

Prints extra blank lines for non-xenodromes:

```python
golf % python2.7 xenodromes.py <<<3
0
1
2
3

5
6
7



11



15



19

21
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
*`ḶbµQ⁼$Ðfḅ³
```

**[TryItOnline!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=KmDhuLZiwrVR4oG8JMOQZuG4hcKz&input=&args=Mw)**

Will work for any `n`, given enough memory, Jelly's base conversion is not restrictive.

#### How?

```
*`ḶbµQ⁼$Ðfḅ³ - Main link: n
    µ        - monadic chain separation
*            - exponentiation with
 `           - repeated argument, i.e. n^n
  Ḷ          - lowered range, i.e. [0,1,2,...,n^n-1]
   b         - covert to base n (vectorises)
        Ðf   - filter keep:
       $     -     last two links as a monad
     Q       -         unique elements
      ⁼      -         equals input (no vectorisation)
           ³ - first program argument (n)
          ḅ  - convert from base (vectorises)
```

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES7), 86 bytes

```
n=>{a=[];for(i=n**n;i--;j||a.unshift(i))for(j=i,b=0;(b^=f=1<<j%n)&f;j=j/n|0);return a}
```

Comment: Fails for `1` (Should output `[0]`, but RangeErrors.)

Comment: Exactly what I had, but this would theoretically fail for `37` if precision weren't an issue, which I think makes it invalid...

Comment: @Artyer I've ported my Batch version, so now this will work for `n` from `1` to `13` before floating-point precision kills it.

Comment: I like how the solutions start off really short, and then suddenly jump an order of magnitude.

Answer (score 2):

### Batch, <s>204</s> 200 bytes

```
@set/an=%1,m=1
@for /l %%i in (1,1,%1)do @set/am*=n
@for /l %%i in (0,1,%m%)do @set/ab=0,j=i=%%i&call:l
@exit/b
:l
@set/a"f&=b^=f=1<<j%%n,j/=n"
@if %f%==0 exit/b
@if %j% gtr 0 goto l
@echo %i%
```

Won't work for n > 9 because Batch only has 32-bit arithmetic. Conveniently, Batch evaluates `f &= b ^= f = 1 << j % n` as `f = 1 << j % n, b = b ^ f, f = f & b` rather than `f = f & (b = b ^ (f = 1 << j % n))`.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, <s>59</s> 48 bytes

```
Select[Range[#^#]-1,xMax[x~DigitCount~#]==1]&
```

Contains U+F4A1 "Private Use" character

## Explanation

```
Range[#^#]-1
```

Generate `{1, 2, ..., n^n}`. Subtract 1. (yields `{0, 1, ..., n^n - 1}`)

```
xMax[x~DigitCount~#]==1
```

A Boolean function: `True` if each digit occurs at most once in base `n`.

```
Select[ ... ]
```

From the list `{0, 1, ..., n^n - 1}`, select ones that give `True` when the above Boolean function is applied.

**59 byte version**

```
Select[Range[#^#]-1,xDuplicateFreeQ[x~IntegerDigits~#]]&
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 47 bytes

```perl6
{(0..$_**$_).grep: !*.polymod($_ xx*).repeated}
```

Returns a [Seq](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Seq). ( [Seq](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Seq) is a basic [Iterable](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Iterable) wrapper for [Iterator](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Iterator)s )

With an input of `16` it takes 20 seconds to calculate the 53905th element of the Seq (`87887`).

### Expanded:

```perl6
{       # bare block lambda with implicit parameter ｢$_｣

  ( 0 .. ($_ ** $_) )    # Range of values to be tested

  .grep:                 # return only those values

    !\                   # Where the following isn't true
    *\                   # the value
    .polymod( $_ xx * )  # when put into the base being tested
    .repeated            # has repeated values
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, <s>48</s> 55 bytes

```
Union[(x   x~FromDigits~#)/@Permutations[Range@#-1,#]]&
```

(The triple space between the `x`s needs to be replaced by the 3-byte character \uF4A1 to make the code work.)

Unnamed function of a single argument. Rather than testing integers for xenodromicity, it simply generates all possible permutations of subsets of the allowed digits (which automatically avoids repetition) and converts the corresponding integers to base 10. Each xenodrome is generated twice, both with and without a leading 0; `Union` removes the duplicates and sorts the list to boot.

Comment: Fails for `2`. The function gives `{0, 1}`. I believe you need `Permutations[Range@#-1, #]` instead of `Subsets[Range@#-1]`.

Comment: Gah, what a boneheaded mistake. Thank you for observing it, and for suggeting the perfect fix!

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
ʁṖƛÞSƛṖ⁰vβ]fU
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLKgeG5lsabw55TxpvhuZbigbB2zrJdZlUiLCIiLCIzIl0=)

```
ʁṖƛÞSƛṖ⁰vβ]fU
ʁ             # Range [0, n)
 Ṗƛ       ]   # For each permutation:
   ÞSƛ        # For each sublist in the permutation:
      Ṗ         # Generate the permutations of that
        v       # For each permutation:
         β        # Treating it as a list of digits, convert to base 10 from base
       ⁰          # <the input>
           f  # Flatten the resulting list
            U # Remove duplicates
```

Comment: ;; can be ] (I think)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 7 bytes

```
eʁ'?τÞu
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJlyoEnP8+Ew551IiwiIiwiMyJd)

```
 ʁ      # Range(0, 
e       # n**n
  '     # Filtered by...
   ?τ   # Convert to base n
     Þu # All unique?
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>100</s> 80 bytes

*-20 bytes thanks to [@Laikoni](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56433/laikoni)*

```hs
f k=[n|n<-[0..k*k^k],let x#0=1>0;x#n|m<-mod n k=notElem m x&&(m:x)#div n k,[]#n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00h2zY6rybPRjfaQE8vWys7LjtWJye1RKFC2cDW0M7AukI5rybXRjc3P0UhD6g2L7/ENSc1VyFXoUJNTSPXqkJTOSWzDCSlEx2rnBf7PzcxM0/BVqGgtCS4pEhBRaE4I78cSKUpmPwHAA)

Comment: 90 bytes by dropping `x` from `(#)` and using a list comprehension for `f`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcyxCsIwEIDhPU9xkFJa0RLBqXhuPoFjiJDQlpZLLmKjZvDdY53@b/pnu9LofSkkFWojSDKGOAAD9Q3JYXn/2YqsDR4vSuTG9q5FjunqxwAWXF1ncGICQs1fPh@06jra0Z3MPlfbzpRgFwaExyvd0hMqWOf42TLBqfwA "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: 88 by merging `(#)` with the test function `x`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/XyNbuULTwNbQzoALzMyrybXRzc1PUchTyLbNyy9xzUnNVchVqFBTA0pr5FpVaKqkZJaBZDW50oBKovNq8mx0ow309LK1suOyY3WylaNjVfJi/@cmZuYp2CoUlJYElxQpqCgUZ@SXA6k0BZP/AA "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: 80 bytes by putting `(#)` into the list comprehension where `k` is given from context: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00h2zY6rybPRjfaQE8vWys7LjtWJye1RKFC2cDW0M7AukI5rybXRjc3P0UhD6g2L7/ENSc1VyFXoUJNTSPXqkJTOSWzDCSlEx2rnBf7PzcxM0/BVqGgtCS4pEhBRaE4I78cSKUpmPwHAA "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 73 bytes

```ruby
->n,*a{i=-1
n>1?(0..n**n).filter_map{i+=1
d=i.digits(n)
i if d==d&d}:[0]}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuhY3PXXt8nS0EqszbXUNufLsDO01DPT08rS08jT10jJzSlKL4nMTC6oztW0NuVJsM_VSMtMzS4o18jS5MhUy0xRSbG1T1FJqraINYmshBu4uUHCLNozlAlFGEMoYQpnEQlQsWAChAQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 14 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
o à cá mìU â ñ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=byDgIGPhIG3sVSDiIPE&input=NC1R)

Explanation:

```
o à cá mìU â ñ
o              # Get the range [0...input]
  à            # Find all arrays containing unique items from that range
    cá         # Find all orderings for each of those arrays
       m       # For each one:
         U     #  Treat it as an array of base-input digits
        ì      #  Convert it to a base-10 number
           â   # Remove duplicates
             ñ # Sort by ascending value
```

[This alternative](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&code=cFUgbyBmX3NVIKVac1Ug4g&input=NA) and [this other alternative](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&code=cFUgbyBmX3NVIPEg5C0gZQ&input=NA) are longer, but seems like that strategy could become shorter if someone finds a better way to check for "contains no duplicate elements".

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>13</s> 10 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
pU ÇìU'âÃâ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=cFUgx%2bxVJ%2bLD4g&input=NA)

```
pU ÇìU'âÃâ     :Implicit input of integer U
pU             :Raised to the power of itself
   Ç           :Map the range [0,U**U)
    ìU         :  Convert to base U digit array
      'â       :  Deduplicate and convert back to integer
        Ã      :End map
         â     :Deduplicate
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
mÝʒIвDÙQ
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/9/DcU5M8L2xyOTwz8P9/EwA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##ASwA0/9vc2FiaWX/NUVOPyIg4oaSICI/TkTCqf9tw53KksKu0LJEw5lR/30swrY//w).<sup>*†*</sup>

**Explanation:**

```python
m         # Push the (implicit) input to the power of the (implicit) input: nⁿ
 Ý        # Pop and push a list in the range [0,nⁿ]
  ʒ       # Filter this list by:
   Iв     #  Convert the integer to base-input as list
     DÙQ  #  Check if all items in this list are unique:
     D    #   Duplicate the list
      Ù   #   Uniquify the items in the copy
       Q  #   Check if the two lists are still the same
          # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

† Note: input \$n=1\$ will output as `[0,1]` instead of `[0]`. This could be fixed in +1 [byte](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) by adding a `¨` after the `Ý`, to make the range \$[0,n^n)\$ instead. However, I'd argue for \$n=1\$ it should be allowed to output either `[0]` or `[0,1]`. If base-1 follows the same rules as the other bases, only `0` can be represented, making it practically useless. Because of that, bijective base-1 (aka [unary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_numeral_system)) is usually used instead when someone talks about base-1, in which case:

1. \$n=0\$ as bijective base-1 will have an empty result (technically all unique)
2. \$n=1\$ as bijective base-1 results in a single tally mark (thus all unique)
3. \$n\geq2\$ as bijective base-1 results in \$n\$ amount of tally mark (thus not all unique)